# Google Play Music can't see WMA files on Pixel 2

Tags: music, google-play-music, google-pixel-2, wma

On my PC, I have a library of WMA files that I have ripped from CDs using iTunes.

About 6 months ago I got Google's Pixel phone, and wanted to load a bunch of the music onto my phone.  A quick online search told me I should just be able to copy it to the **Music** folder on my phone.

I did so, and I got a popup telling me it might not play in its current format, and did I want to convert it before copying?  I clicked "Yes", and the music was copied, and showed up in Google Play Music.

Recently I got the Pixel 2, and went through the same steps to copy music to my phone, but after copying it I don't see any of it in Google Play Music.  I installed VLC and it can see/play the music, but it has very limited capabilities as a music player and isn't compatible with the Google Assistant, so I'd really rather use Play Music.

I tried copying an MP3 file onto the phone, and that shows up in Play Music, so it must have something to do with the format.  I'd really rather not have to convert my entire music library en masse to MP3.

I'm running Android Oreo 8.0.0.

I've verified that there is no `.nomedia` file in the **Music** folder.

- **Is there some difference between the Pixel and Pixel 2 that prevents Google Play Music from seeing WMA files on the Pixel 2?**
- **Is there something else I might need to do to be able to play them?**

---

**EDIT**:
I tried @Abochur's suggestion in the comments of playing a file via the file manager, and it would not play from there, which indicates to me that there is a problem with the file.  I tried re-copying one of the files onto the phone, and again I was asked if I wanted the file to be converted so that it could be played, but again it was not recognized once it was on the phone.

I would still like to know why this method worked on my original Pixel but doesn't seem to work on my Pixel 2, and if there's any way to have my music appear in Google Play Music without mass-converting all of it to a different format.

Comment: Find out if Google music doesn't support this music, by going into your file manager and playing the music from there. If the music works through Google music then it must be that it supports wmv, and something else is the problem